# What are the best solutions like redis for sorting in a trading engine?

Tags: java, redis, scalability, trading, sortedlist

I found sorted set of redis is a good option, but I want to be sure to choose a high performance and scalable solution for a trading engine. The response time is so important and I want to know, is redis the best solution to sort the orders, are there any better options for this?

Comment: Can you add some more details about what this system looks like? Redis is a very fast and flexible tool and can be useful for a great many things, this one is likely one of them. However, it's hard to say without some more details like what are you actually sorting, is it just IDs or whole objects? how large are the lists/sets you're sorting within or is it just a global list?